# Xamarin.Forms.Device.StartTimer - cannot catch the exact second or millisecond

Tags: xamarin, timer, xamarin.forms

I have a counter in my Xamarin.Forms application and I try to execute a speech right when it reaches exact seconds or milliseconds but It never gets executed.

Here is the code sample:

```
Xamarin.Forms.Device.StartTimer(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1000), () =>
{
    ts = sw.Elapsed;
    lblTimer.Text = String.Format("{0:00}:{1:00}", ts.Minutes, ts.Seconds);

    if (ts.Seconds == 45)
        Plugin.TextToSpeech.CrossTextToSpeech.Current.Speak("45 seconds");

    if (ts.TotalSeconds == 60)
        Plugin.TextToSpeech.CrossTextToSpeech.Current.Speak("120 seconds");

    if (ts.TotalSeconds > 60 && ts.TotalSeconds <61)
        Plugin.TextToSpeech.CrossTextToSpeech.Current.Speak("1 minute.!");
});
```

The code above will only execute the last when it is between. I tried both `Seconds` and `TotalSeconds` as well as `MilliSeconds` and `TotalMilliseconds`. When I try to use equal it doesn't work. It only works when it is greater or smaller.

Comment: Each platform has different timer implementations (on Android they are using a private `Looper`) and has to invoke a callback **after** your 1000ms timespan has ended, your `Elapsed` will never be *guaranteed* to match your timespan interval...

Comment: do you mind a small sample or if you know a link about it?

Comment: A sample of what?

Answer (score 0):

Both `TotalSeconds` and `TotalMilliseconds` returns as a fractional part of second as a double, so your check will fail.
You can either parse that value as an int or use this:

```
if(Math.Abs(ts.TotalSeconds - 60) <= 1)
    ...
```

Comment: I will try that but I recognized it and tried also    if (ts.TotalSeconds == 60.0) is that not supposed to be double? btw ts.Seconds is integer, why would this one not work?

Comment: I tried your code. it is not working if I use equal only. Unfortunately it is not a solution for me. thanks for the info anyway

Comment: You shouldn't use the equality, you can't be sure if the timer will match your equality member. If you really want to use the equal operator try `(int)ts.TotalSeconds == 45` for example.

Comment: read my question again please. my question is to exact match. I achieve already greater or smaller. Doing int doesnt work either. as I wrote above Seconds is type of int and it doesnt work.

Comment: But you won't get an exact match, because timers simply aren't that exact. You ultimately have to use some rounded value somewhere (which is what casting to int does). You can just output the total seconds to the console and see the values to see that Zroq means.